Nodejs Worker_threads not work on worker side
I have 3 files with test.js, main_worker.js, and worker.js.
First, test.js
const multiTask = require('./main_worker.js');

function processNextStep(results) {
  console.log('Do something with allPrimes:', results.length);
}

function process() {
  multiTask(processNextStep);

}

process();


Second, main_worker.js
const {
  Worker,
  isMainThread,
  workerData,
} = require("worker_threads");
const generatePrimes = require('./worker.js');

let min = 2,
  max = 10_000_000,
  allPrimes = [];
function multiTask(callback) {
  try {
    if (isMainThread) {
      const threadCount = 8;
      const threads = new Set();
      const range = Math.ceil((max - min) / threadCount); 
  
      let start = min;
      console.time("prime2");
  
      for (let i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        const wStart = start;
        const worker = new Worker(__dirname + '/worker.js', { workerData: { start: wStart, range: range, min:min } });
        threads.add(worker);
        start += range;
      }
  
      for (let worker of threads) {
        console.log('worker.threadId : ', worker.threadId);
        worker.on("error", (err) => {
          console.log(`Worker ${worker.threadId} error:`, err);
        });

        worker.on('online', (a)=>{
          console.log('worker online a : ', a)
        })
  
        worker.on("exit", (code) => {
          console.log(`Worker ${worker.threadId} stopped with exit code ${code}`);
          threads.delete(worker);
  
          if (threads.size === 0) {
            console.timeEnd("prime2");
            console.log('Total primes:', allPrimes.length);
            callback(allPrimes);
          }
        });
  
        worker.on("message", (msg) => {
          console.log('Received message from worker:', msg.length);
          allPrimes.push(...msg);
        });
      }
    } else {
      try {
        console.log('Worker thread started with data:', workerData);
        generatePrimes(workerData.start, workerData.range);
        console.log('Generated primes:', result.length);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in worker thread:', error);
      }
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: :;:: ', error)
  }
}

module.exports = multiTask;

Finally, worker.js
const { parentPort } = require("worker_threads");

console.log('do worker ');

function generatePrimes(param) {
  const {start, range, min} = param;
  let primes = [];
  let isPrime = true;
  const end = start + range;
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    for (let j = min; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
      if (i !== j && i % j === 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isPrime) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
    isPrime = true;
  }
  parentPort.postMessage(primes);
}

module.exports = generatePrimes;


and I call node test.js then the log is bellow.
do worker 
worker.threadId :  1
worker.threadId :  2
worker.threadId :  3
worker.threadId :  4
worker.threadId :  5
worker.threadId :  6
worker.threadId :  7
worker.threadId :  8
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
worker online a :  undefined
do worker 
do worker 
do worker 
do worker 
do worker 
do worker 
do worker 
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
do worker 
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
Worker -1 stopped with exit code 0
prime2: 71.644ms
Total primes: 0
Do something with allPrimes: 0

I think it doesnt work "generatePrimes" function.
firstly the worker threadId is normal.
but, worker.on("exit", () => ~~  under the worker threadId is not normal as you can see on the log above.
how to fix this worker thread?
please help me.
